# Polymer 1.x dom-repeat does not work properly

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to use the dom-repeat helper in **Polymer 1.x** to display a list of articles.

After connecting to Firebase the data is correctly stored in my *lbriefe*-array.

However the dom-repeat-template fails to pass the properties of my objects in *lbriefe* to my custom element *leserbriefe*.

This is my dom-repeat-template:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[lbriefe]]" initial-count="3">
  <lb-leserbrief
  heading$="[[item.heading]]" 
  author$="[[item.author]]" 
  reference$="[[item.reference]]" 
  content$="[[item.content]]" 
  source$="[[item.source]]"
  date$="[[item.date]]"
  >
  </lb-leserbrief>
</template>
```

And here is my script:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'lb-leserbriefe',
  properties: {
    lbriefe: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {return [];},
          notify: true
      }
  },

  ready: function(){
    const leserbriefRef = firebase.database().ref('leserbriefe');
    const divList = this.$.lbbriefe;
        leserbriefRef.on('value', snap => {
            this.lbriefe = [
              {
                heading: "Test",
                author: "Daniel",
                reference: "Kein",
                content: "<p>Test Test</p>",
                source: "Ich",date: "31. August 2016"
              }
              ];
            for(var i=0; i<13; i++){
                this.lbriefe[i] = snap.child('l'+i).val();
            }
            console.log(this.lbriefe);
        });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You work with `lbriefe` array directly, however in order to notify Polymer binding about array mutations you should use [special API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#array-mutation)

So in your case just use push method to add items to array

```
this.push("lbriefe", item)
```